# Multiple index types in Swift

Tags: swift, parameter-passing, type-inference

In Swift (a language I'm still fairly new to), I'm trying to define a class that allows indexing using either an `Int` or `Range<Int>`. For example:

```
var m = Matrix(rows: 10, cols: 10)
var v = m[1, 0..<10]
```

The two ways I can think of allowing this issue is to either adding an extension to the Range class:

```
extension Range {
  init(_ intValue:Element) {
    self.init(start: intValue, end: intValue.successor())
  }
}
```

or to create an enum that allows for either type:

```
enum IndexType {
    case value(Int)
    case range(Range<Int>)

    init(_ v:Int) {
        self = .value(v)
    }

    init(_ r:Range<Int>) {
        self = .range(r)
    }
}
```

However, neither solution works as intended, as I still need to specify the type manually. For example, given the function:

```
func slice(indices:IndexType...) -> [Double] {
  // ...
}
```

I can't then just do:

```
slice(1, 3...4, 5)
```

but instead have to do:

```
slice(IndexType(1), IndexType(3...4), 5)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Swift? I'm used to c++, which would do type inference automatically, but the same doesn't appear to work with Swift.

One similar question I found was: 
[Swift Arrays of Multiple Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212529/swift-arrays-of-multiple-types)

However, I really would like to avoid the use of `Any` as I know the two types it should be.

Comment: Have you seen subscripts??

Comment: Yes, in actuality I'm using subscripts, but I didn't mention them to keep the problem simpler (I didn't want to include an entire class in the description). I don't think subscripts are related to the problem described above, as you still have to deal with the problem of mixed types in the parameter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protocol MatrixIndex {
    var Matrix_range: Range<Int> { get }
}

extension Int : MatrixIndex {
    var Matrix_range: Range<Int> {
        get {
            return Range<Int>(start: self, end: self+1)
        }
    }
}

extension Range : MatrixIndex {
    var Matrix_range: Range<Int> {
        get {
            return Range<Int>(start: self.startIndex as! Int, end: self.endIndex as! Int)
        }
    }
}

class Matrix {
    subscript(row: MatrixIndex, column: MatrixIndex) -> () {
        get {
            print("getting \(row.Matrix_range) \(column.Matrix_range)")
        }

        set(newValue) {
            print("setting \(row.Matrix_range) \(column.Matrix_range)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks like it works. Thanks! One minor point, returning `()` appears to make the `set` not work correctly, but that can be fixed by changing it to a sensible return type.